Can the coefficients of a Taylor series be expressed as rational functions for an affine variety?
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $V \subseteq k^n$ an affine variety corresponding to a prime ideal $P \subseteq k[t_1, \dots, t_n]$. For $x\in V$ let $O_x = \{p/q \mid p,q\in k[t_1, \dots, t_n]/P, q(x) \neq 0 \}$ and $m_x \subseteq O_x$ the maximal ideal of all $f\in O_x$ with $f(x) = 0$. Choose a basis $u_1, \dots, u_m$ of the vector space $m_x/m_x^2$. Following the definition in Basic Algebraic Geometry 1, Igor R. Shafarevich, p. 101 a Taylor series of $f\in O_x$ is a formal expression $F_0 + F_1 + \dots $ where $F_i$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $k[T_1, \dots, T_m]$ of degree $i$ such that
$f - S_l(u_1, \dots, u_m) \in m_x^{l+1}$ with $S_l = \sum_{i=0}^l F_i$.
If $x$ is non-singular, then the Taylor series is unique. Now fix $f = p/q$ with $p,q\in k[t_1, \dots, t_n]/P$. We may consider the Taylor series $F_{0,x}+F_{1,x}+\dots$ at different non-singular points $x\in V$ with $q(x) \neq 0$. I have the following question.

Can the coefficients in $F_{i,x}$ be expressed as $p'(x)/q'(x)$ for appropriate $p', q' \in k[t_1, \dots, t_n]/P$?

For example we always have $F_{0,x} = f(x)$ and the case $V = k$ is simply $F_{i,x} = \frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(x)T^i$. Note that the question is ill-posed, since the Taylor series depends on the choice of a basis of $m_x/m_x^2$ in each point $x\in V$. (For the case $V = k$ we chose $t-x \in m_x$ as a basis.) So we should additionally depand that we choose the basis appropriately to get the property in the question. If this is not possible globally, then maybe at least locally?

As you note at the end, the Taylor series depends on a basis. Say $\dim(V) = m$. Choose regular functions $u_1, \ldots, u_m$ and an open subset $U$ of the set of nonsingular points of $V$ such that for each $a \in U$, the elements $u_i - a_i$, $i = 1, \ldots, m$, span $m_a/m_a^2$ (where we wrote $a_i := u_i(a)$). Then for each $f \in k[U]$ and each $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_m)$ the coefficient of $\prod_{i=1}^m(u_i - a_i)^{\alpha_i}$ in the Taylor expansion of $f$ in $k[[u_1 - a_1, \ldots, u_m - a_m]]$ is a regular function on $U$.
I am sure this is a "standard" fact, but do not know of any textbook that proves it. The only reference I know is Lemma 3.5 of Bierstone and Milman's "Canonical desingularization in characteristic zero by blowing up the maximum strata of a local invariant" (the arxiv link for the first chapter) - note that the proof of Lemma 3.5 is valid for arbitrary characteristic.
